# Xcodebuild output file name

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, xcodebuild

I'am building a Cocoa Library in C++  using XCode4. I wonder if there is an option in the commandline xcodebuild to change output file name other than the project name.

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos(iOSVersion) -configuration (configuration) build PLATFORM_NAME=iphoneos  *OUT_FILE_NAME*=myfilename
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As a walkaround to this problem, we can rename output filename with the move command `mv` after the command `xcodebuild`:

```
mv Out_Dir/PROJECT_NAME.a Out_Dir/NEW_OUTPUT_NAME.a
```